# How can I calculate the worst-case Tj of a MOSFET in discontinuous operation at another Tamb?

Tags: mosfet, temperature, tolerance, loss, rdson

I am faced with the task to calculate the maximum junction temperature of a MOSFET in a half-bridge, having conduction losses, switching losses and diode losses. The real difficulty comes from the discontiuous operation of the device. The device is powered only for a small time (say one minute), before temperatures have stabilized which means that thermal resistances of the whole heat sinking system is more or less irrelevant, it seems to be dominantly the capacitive terms that matter.

Up to now, I solved this on a very simplified approach: maximize the switching loss by increased capacitance and snubbers, operate the device at the maximum load at room temperature, measure peak case temperature and calculate the junction temperature from thermal impedance of the MOSFET and measured losses. In the end, the difference to the maximum ambient temperature is added, and a peak junction temperature concluded.

This however, seems to be wrong for at least two reasons:

1. The actual MOSFET of my measurement might have a much lower initial \$R_{DS,on}\$ than a worst case component. A tolerance of 20% between typical and max seems not to be unusual.
2. The initial \$R_{DS,on}\$ is even higher, when a measurement is done at increased ambient temperature. In my MOSFETS's case (NTMFD5C466N) the increase from 25°C to 50°C means another 10% higher resistance.

So if the initial conduction loss could be 30% higher, the contribution of them will be even higher than 30% because the \$R_{DS,on}\$ will also rise quicker. But how much will this be?

I have some ideas to find an answer to this:

1. Ask the manufacturer for a component that is at the upper tolerance end of \$R_{DS,on}\$ and measure at real worst-case ambient temperature.
2. Use a MOSFET of the same series with \$R_{DS,on}\$ at least of the maximum of my actual type.
3. Measure "a lot" of typical systems at the maximum ambient temperature and do a statistics based estimaten of the worst case.
4. Make a detailed simulation model of the heat sink and try to simulate it (seems to be the most difficult approach).

What do you suggest here?

Comment: Maybe the Transient Data section of this app note is helpful: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8220-D.PDF

Comment: Thank you! Quite overwhelming document, I will need time to digest this...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest measuring the characteristics of the parts you have (rdson, etc) and then measure the temperature. Compare this with your calculations to gain confidence in your model.

Then you can recalculate temperature based on worst case component characteristics.

Also note that Rdson is based on junction temperature, and not only ambient.

Also, 1 minute seems a long time. I would design for steady-state.

Comment: How should the OP measure the temperature of **the die**?

Comment: Good question. I was thinking that he should calculate based on the given Theta_jc. I was pointing out that when he calculates Rdson, he should consider junction temp instead of ambient.

I once made a circuit to put a small current through the FET just after it turns off to measure the internal diode drop. Separately, I characterized the diode drop vs temperature with steady state conditions in a temp chamber.